# Visual Studio 2010 sponsored tag icon does not fit

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, sponsored-tags

Is it just me or does image for the [sponsored tag for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=visual-studio&sort=info) not fit?

Maybe I am just a detail freak, but it bugs me a bit.  It looks more like an X than the infinity sign.

Comment: Yeah it could have been sized better.

Comment: Ouch. Please remove `&pagesize=50` from the link, it makes a persistent change in the paging preference.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way it was provided to us. 16x16 pixels isn't a lot, so they picked that way. I think it's fine, personally.